# Why doesn't this use of javascript functions in an array work?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I am trying to create an array of functions so I can call one depending on an index.
The set function doesn't work.  The setF1 and setF2 functions do.
What is the design decision that made things work this way?

You can find the test page at jrootham.tjddev.net/test/test.html

I can't seem to paste the test code here.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>     
  <head>    
  <script type="text/javascript">
  var thing =
  {
    f1 : function() {alert(1);},
    f2 : function() {alert(2);},
    setF1 : function() {this.call = this.f1;},
    setF2 : function() {this.call = this.f2;},
    list : [this.f1, this.f2],
    set: function(index){this.call=this.list[index];},
    call : this.f1
  }
  </script>     
  </head>     
  <body>
    <button type="button" onClick="thing.set(0)">Set 0</button>     
    <button type="button" onClick="thing.set(1)">Set 1</button>     
    <button type="button" onClick="thing.setF1()">Set F1</button>     
    <button type="button" onClick="thing.setF2()">Set F2</button>     
    <button type="button" onClick="thing.call()">Call</button>     
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `{}` creates an `object`; `[]` creates an `array`. There is a significant difference between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why this doesn't work is because `this` in the context of `call:this.f1` is actually referencing `window` and *not* `thing`.

`this` is only referencing `thing` from **within** `thing`'s member functions.

The following *would* work however:

```
var thing = { //watch out for semicolon insertion...
  f1 : function() {alert(1);},
  f2 : function() {alert(2);},
  setF1 : function() {this.call = this.f1;},
  setF2 : function() {this.call = this.f2;},
  set: function(index){ this.call=this.list[index]; },
  call : function() {
     this.f1();
  }
};
thing.list = [thing.f1, thing.f2];
```

Comment: Inside thing: [this.f1, this.f2] doesn't work because this==window; [thing.f1, thing.f2] doesn't work because thing is not defined yet.